# Decrypting data from MagTek iDynamo encrypted card reader

Tags: encryption, 3des

Does anyone have reference code (even if pseudo-code) for decrypting data from a MagTek iDynamo encrypted card reader?  The ANSI X9.24 standard is... lacking... in the pseudo-code and readability department.  I have the master key, KSN, and cipher text and need to derive the session key and get to the clear text.  I've implemented an algorithm similar to the one found [here](http://www.andyorrock.com/2006/11/creating_an_ipe.html) and added a loop based on the counter portion of the KSN but it still doesn't produce actual card track data.

Comment: Have you solved the problem ? If yes, could you please share your solution. I am also stuck on the same point. Thanks.

Comment: @haxor : could you please share your solution with us ?

Comment: @joelc did you find the solution?

Comment: I had to work directly with MagTek.  They, at the time, did not provide code that would perform the task, however, they provided the specific steps and guidelines and what must be performed within each step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the DUKPT class i wrote to do what you need:

https://github.com/mburshteyn1/DUKPT

Comment: Hi misha, In that code What string need to passed to the decrypt method. Also PEK keys were generated at the end of variantKeys() method but where DEK was generated. How do we encrypt the keys in our device. Can u enlighten  me please

Comment: Hi, the string you pass is the encrypted string from the credit card reader.  Not sure what you mean by DEK.  The BDK?  The device I was using came encrypted fro mthe manufactured with a certain BDK which they also sent me.  Let me know if this clarifies things.