# How do I get the iDynamo 5 Base Derivation Key (BDK)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm using the Magtek iDynamo 5 mag stripe reader to process gift cards in my POS system, but I need the track data unencrypted in order to get the gift card's number.  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097592/decrypting-data-from-magtek-idynamo-encrypted-card-reader), which solves the problem of decrypting the data, however, I need the BDK for my device.  Is this printed somewhere? Derived from the serial number? Universal to all iDynamo devices?

Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: If you follow the links you will get statements like "BDK obtained from the device provider". So have you asked your device provider?

Comment: I have started the process, but tech support is not being the most responsive.  I'm basically just trying to make sure it's not called something else in their documentation or derived from numbers that I already have.  The official documentation is lacking to say the least.

Comment: Fair enough and it could help other devs. I'm not sure if it can be resolved without support from the supplier though. If you do get an answer from them, could you please post the gist here as an answer? You can then accept your own answers and I would be happy to vote on it.

Comment: So far I've found out that an iDynamo purchased at retail has a private key that is not available to the public, it can only be used with Magtek's own key management service that has an annual fee per iDynamo device.  Hoping they have an option with a custom private key.  Will definitely post an answer when I have one.

Answer (score 5):

Magtek iDynamos purchased at retail have a private key for the Magensa.net payment gateway/service.  You cannot decrypt the data from these cards because they will not provide the Base Derivation Key (BDK) to you because it is private to their service.

They provide web services at an annual fee per iDynamo device to decrypt card swipe data.  They can decrypt and return the data or submit it to a payment gateway on your behalf.  It also seems some payment gateways have the ability to do this decryption for you.

In my particular case I do need to decrypt the card swipe data, so for that, Magtek can create a private key for you for a one-time $250 fee.  In order to do this you must first purchase a development iDynamo from them ($95 + tax & shipping) that has a known (ANSI Standard) key that they will provide a BDK for so you can verify that you can perform the DUPKT decryption.  After you have verified that you can do the decryption they will generate a custom private key for you, send it to you, and give you a KSID that you can use to order iDynamo readers or other Magtek products that can be decrypted using your private key.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Going through the process now. They sent me the ANSI key and 2 components. Do I need to do anything to create the BDK or do they send that to you?

Comment: @powermikee Did you figure out your question? I'm in the same boat

Comment: same here, trying to decrypt to use on mobile clients custom app... any more  hints on this?

Comment: @zumzum Any luck on it? I was pretty sure I got the BDK from the two hexadecimal components they mailed by XORing their values together, but it doesn't seem so since my decrypted output is messed up.

Comment: @mdimarca No luck. Sorry. I have reviewed this issue quite thoroughly and it seems to me that Magtek makes it quite more confusing than it actually is if you want to decrypt data bypassing Magensia.... for obvious $$$ rasons I guess. I'll figure it out eventually. When I do I'll post the solution here so everybody can use it.

Comment: @zumzum I believe I figured it out. To get the BDK, you need to XOR the two "Key Components" Magtek provides for $250 and mails. However, you need to make sure the Magtek reader you purchase is set for the BDK and NOT the test key. They mailed me a reader and it only works for the test ANSI they emailed me. They said to let them know I want future readers to be set to work with the BDK instead.

Comment: @zumzum to decrypt, this is the only library I found that works off the bat: https://github.com/mburshteyn1/DUKPT

Comment: @mdimarca I tested that library, but I wasn't able to make it work. I am not saying the library is no good, it might be just great, but I wasn't able to make it work with the information Magtek sent over...

Comment: @zumzum hope you end up getting it to work too. I struggled with it for a while. For the test device, the ANSI was the only key that worked. I used the ANSI in place of a real BDK. Also, the KSN will be inaccurate unless you set up the device properly. If you print the swipe count of the reader and it's -1, the following might fix it up (for the cDynamo but probably other devices too): [self.mtSCRALib setDeviceType:MAGTEKIDYNAMO];//has to be iDynamo to get any of the data
    [self.mtSCRALib setDeviceProtocolString:@"com.magtek.idynamo"];